# Raphael JS image animation performance

Tags: javascript, math, animation, raphael

I'm trying to create an image animation using Raphael JS.

I want the effect of a bee moving randomly across the page, I've got a working example but it's a bit "jittery", and I'm getting this warning in the console:

"Resource interpreted as image but transferred with MIME type text/html"

I'm not sure if the warning is causing the "jittery" movement or its just the way I approached it using maths.

If anyone has a better way to create the effect, or improvements please let me know.

I have a demo online [here](http://letsgojuno.com/prototypes/bee_demo/)

and heres my javascript code:

```
function random(min, max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;  
} 

function BEE(x, y, scale) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.s = scale;
    this.paper = Raphael("head", 915, 250);

    this.draw = function() {
        this.paper.clear();
        this.paper.image("bee.png", this.x, this.y, 159*this.s, 217*this.s);
    }

    this.update = function() {
        var deg = random(-25, 25);

        var newX = Math.cos(Raphael.rad(deg)) * 2;
        var newY = Math.sin(Raphael.rad(deg)) * 2;

        this.x += newX;
        this.y += newY;

        if( this.x > 915) {
            this.x = 0;
        }
        if( this.y > 250 || this.y < 0 ) {
            this.y = 125;
        }
    }
}

$(document).ready(function() {

    var bee = new BEE(100, 150, 0.4);
    var timer = setInterval(function(){
        bee.draw();
        bee.update();
    }, 15);
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are not using Raphael's best feature, the ability to just set attributes on objects you create, just like the DOM. You are re-instantiating the bee and clearing the paper at every step. This is how you would do it with the canvas tag, and it's so tedious error-prone, let the browser worry about what to repaint.

A better way to do what you are doing is the following

```
/**
 * I don't like closure object orientation, but if you're
 * going to use it, use it all the way
 * (instead of using this.x and this.y for private variables)
 */
function Bee(paper, x, y, scale) 
{

    // The Raphael img object for the bee)
    var img = paper.image("bee.png", x, y, 159 * scale, 217 * scale);

    var timerId = null;

    // Allows access to 'this' within closures
    var me = this;

    this.draw = function() {
      img.attr({x: x, y: y});
    }

    this.update = function() {
        var deg = random(-25, 25);

        var newX = Math.cos(Raphael.rad(deg)) * 2;
        var newY = Math.sin(Raphael.rad(deg)) * 2;

        x += newX;
        y += newY;

        if( x > 915) {
            x = 0;
        }
        if( y > 250 || y < 0 ) {
            y = 125;
        }
    }

    this.fly = function() {
        timerId = setInterval({
            me.update();
            me.draw();
        }, 15);
    }

    this.stop = function() {
      clearInterval(timerId);
      timerId = null;
    } 

    function random(min, max) {
        return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;  
    } 
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    var paper = Raphael("head", 915, 250);
    var bees = [ new Bee(paper, 100, 150, 0.4), new Bee(paper, 50, 10, 0.2) ];
    bees[0].fly();
    bees[1].fly();
    $(document).click(
        bees[0].stop();
        bees[1].stop();
    );

}
```

Comment: thanks, I've taken your advice. I created the bee object so I could add more if I needed too. With this new way when i create another bee it creates a whole new Raphael.paper object. I've tried setting a global var paper = Raphael(...) that doesn't work, any tips. Sorry I only found Raphael yesterday. thanks again

Comment: I've actually never written a line of Rafael code, but I've been watching it and think it's pretty awesome.  Let me adjust the example so you can have multiple bees in one canvas, that means passing the paper into the Bee object, then you can mark it answered.

Comment: By the way, it's not the new way that creates the new paper, your code was doing that previously.